# onKeyPress not working in SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: swiftui

I would like to respond to the arrow keys. Unfortunately, `onKeyPress` doesn't work, I just hear the macOS sound. Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, press arrow up!")
        }
        .onKeyPress(.upArrow) {
            print("I am here")
            return .handled
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a keydown event?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.focusable()` as shown in the example code (or after `Text`).

See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onkeypress(_:action:)

"Performs an action if the user presses a key on a hardware keyboard while the view has focus."

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, press arrow up!")
        }
        .focusable() // <--- here
        .onKeyPress(.upArrow) {
            print("I am here")
            return .handled
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1

Test code showing updating the UI while the `upArrow` is pressed

```
 struct ContentView: View {
     @State private var count = 0
     
     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             Text("Hello, press arrow up! \(count)" )
         }
         .focusable()
         .onKeyPress(.upArrow) {
             count += 1
             return .handled
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! You should also mention in your answer, that you need to add `.focusEffectDisabled()` if one doesn't like the focus shape.

Comment: You may also want to mention, that if someone will try to update the UI during the key is constantly pressed, you should use a `DispatchQueue.main.async` to do that, otherwise the pressing will only change the UI once.

Comment: The UI updates for me without using `DispatchQueue.main.async`. See my EDIT-1 test code.

Comment: What if you hold the key pressed? For me it then only changes once.

Comment: Yes, it works for me even if I hold the key pressed, the `count` updates the UI.
I'm on MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on  MacOS 14.4. It could be different on older systems.